# Get line of error of a Nodejs eval

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm wondering how I'd come about getting line error in eval.

eg.,

```
try {
    eval("var hello = 5; hello hello");
} catch(err) {
    console.log(err.line) // should print 2
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you are in Node, i'd rather use the vm package as it is safer. 
Here is a working solution

```
const vm = require('vm');

// this is the sandbox, it gives the scrip only access to these vars, which 
makes it safer than a pure eval;
const sandbox = {
  count: 2
};


try {
    // create script to be ran
    // I use backtick for new lines
    const script = new vm.Script(
        `count += 1; 

        throw new Error('test');`
    );

    // create the context from the sandbox
    const context = new vm.createContext(sandbox);

    // run the script
    script.runInContext(context,  {
        lineOffset: 0,
        displayErrors: true,
    });
} catch(e) {
    console.log('Line of error :', e.stack.split('evalmachine.<anonymous>:')[1].substring(0, 1))
}
```

Running this code will log `Line of error: 3`.

Here is the doc for the vm package: https://nodejs.org/api/vm.html

Comment: This works great, but there's one thing: If you create a new vm.Script with the code "(", it won't print line error, but instead crash the program.

Comment: I have updated the code, it works much better. It will not crash anymore if you but an invalid syntax in the script